# Excel: Why does double-clicking in a cell jump to a different cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, editing, double-click

Normally, when you double-click a cell, you enter in-cell editing mode, right? This works most of the time, but *occasionally* on random cells, a **double-click instead moves the focus to a different cell** in the sheet, as if I had simply single-clicked that other cell. If I then double-click the original cell again, it works as expected: I can edit the contents of that cell and everything is normal.

This happens on random cells, regardless what their contents are, and of course they're not hyperlinked or anything like that. It happens on several versions of Excel (XP, 2000, 2003, for certain; can't remember earlier versions). It happens on any computer (at home, at work, at previous workplace...).

This is not a major problem I need to have solved, but why in the world is Excel behaving like that?! I'd just like to understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you double click on (or really near) the border of the cell, the selected cell jumps to the first empty cell to the left in the same row (if it was a side border) or up in the same column (if it was a top/bottom border).

It seems to be more reliable if your cursor is closer to a corner rather than in the middle of a border.

Comment: +1 - Reproduced in 2007.  Solution - click carefully in the middle of the cell, or use F2!

Comment: Wow, I never noticed a connection between *where* in the cell I was clicking and the jump direction; it just seemed so random. I also didn't notice that the random target cell was always blank. Wow. Been using Excel since version 0.95 on the Mac in 1986 and still learn new tricks. Amazing!

Comment: Haha, this happened to me as well, and I eventually realized that it would happen if you double click the border - really frustrating. +1 to the answer though.

Comment: Is there any method to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

A) One solution, if the original cell is still visible after the focus has jumped to another cell, is to single click the border of the original cell that was double-clicked to bring the focus back to the original cell.

B) Yes, as shown below, it's possible to disable the behavior.
However, the downside is that you lose the fill handle and cell drag-and-drop features.

(from: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4304-excel-double-click-jumps-to-bottom.html)
Disable Double-Click On Cell Border to Jump to Bottom [Top/Side]:
To disable double-click on cell border feature, you can go to the Excel Options to configure an option as shown below:

1. Click File > Options to go to the Excel Options dialog box.
2. In the Excel Options dialog box, click Advanced option from the left pane, and then uncheck the Enable fill handle and cell drag-and-drop option under the Editing options...
3. Then click OK to close this dialog box, and now, double-click on cell border feature is disabled at once.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure "NUM LK" (number lock) is on. It's the top left key in the numeric keypad on your keyboard, above "7."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1177101)